# min-max-normalized spatiotemporal matrix?

Tags: normalization, spatial

I am using time-series cross-section (TSCS) data and I will like to estimate the following model.

$y_{i,t}=\alpha+ \beta \sum_{j=1}^nw_{i,j,t}y_{i,t}+ \varepsilon_{i,t}$

Where $y_{i,t}$ denotes the dependent variable corresponding to unit $i$ at time $t$. The weighted average $\sum_{j=1}^nw_{i,j,t}y_{i,t}$ is the spatial lag. $w_{i,j,t}$ (with $w_{i,i,t} = 0$) are spatio temporal weights. They account for the level of competition between firm $i$ and its competitor $j$, and vary for every period.  $ε_{i,t}$ is a disturbance term.

My question relates to the construction of the spatio-temporal  $w_{i,j,t}$. I would like to create a a minmax-normalized matrix (Kelejian & Prucha 2010). In a spatial model with no time dimension $w_{i,j}$ every cell ($i,j$th element) of $w_{i,j}$ is divided by $m = min\{maxi(ri),maxi(ci)\}$ with $maxi(ri)$ being the largest row sum of W and $maxi(ci)$ being the largest column sum of W. The advantage of this approach compared to row-normalization, is that normalizing by a scalar preserves symmetry and the basic model specification (Drukker et al 2013).

Does anyone know is this done if the spatial matrix includes a temporal dimension $w_{i,j,t}$? Do I need to do a minmax-normalization for each period separately, or should I use the full matrix?

Comment: Can you please edit so your formulas become readable, that is, using $\LaTeX$?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I see the formulas correctly displayed in the question. they are in latex in between two $ signs

Comment: Formulas in the fourth paragraph is not!